# How to build a selection of Qt5 submodules from source?

Tags: qt, build, qt5

The Qt download page (http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.2/) offers multiple source archives that can be used to build Qt5 from source. One contains all sources, which I managed to build successfully, but it takes rather long and contains a lot of stuff that I do not use.

They also offer submodule source packages that can be used to only build a subset of what Qt offers. Howerver I could not find a manual on how to properly build these. I need the QtBase and the QtXmlPatterns packages. I manged to build the QtBase package on its own, but I would like to know how to build multiple of the submodules.

The QtXmlPatterns package can not be build on its own, so I tried to simply copy the sources from the QtXmlPatterns submodule into the QtBase submodule. But that gives me errors when I execute the configure step.

**So what is the correct procedure for combining multiple of the submodule source packages into one setup that can be build?**

Thank you for your time.

Edit:
Not sure if it is relevant, but I am building Qt5.12.2 on Windows with Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: May I ask how to build just QtBase? I'm still in the stage where I'm able to build everything but not just individual componennts.

Comment: I think you must download the qtbase-everywhere-src package from http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.14/5.14.2/submodules/. This package can be build exactly like the full package that can be found at http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.14/5.14.2/single/. I assume that you have build the full package successfully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The build flow is a bit different from building the full source package.

- configure and build qtbase stand-alone as you have already done it. Use a PREFIX so that you can call `make install` and install the build results to some location in your file system.
- you may want to add the resulting bin folder to your PATH environment variable
- extract the other submodule you want to build into a separate folder
- run `qmake`, `make` and `make install` on your submodule as if it was a "normal" Qt project. This will install the submodule to the PREFIX location of qtbase.

Comment: What is PREFIX?

Comment: PREFIX is the `-prefix` parameter for Qt's configure tool when building qtbase. It's the installation location.